# False min and max assignments in function

Tags: c, struct, assign

I have a function which is supposed to find min and max in an array using struct.
But somehow the function assigns wrong values to min and max variables. Could someone please explain where do I have the mistake? Thank you very much. P.S. In my assignment the function doesn't need to take the first element of the array

```
min_max_t min_max(unsigned int *array, int size)
{
    min_max_t flag;
    flag.min = array[1];
    flag.max = array[1];
    printf("Flag.min: %d | ", flag.min);
    printf("Flag.max: %d\n", flag.max);
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("i = %d - [A:%d - Min:%d - Max:%d]\n", i, array[i], flag.min, flag.max);
        if(array[i] > flag.max)
        {
            flag.max = array[i];
        }
        else if (array[i] < flag.min)
        {
            flag.min = array[i];
        }
        printf("i = %d - [A:%d - Min:%d - Max:%d]\n\n", i, array[i], flag.min, flag.max);
    }
    return flag;
}
```

[Screenshot of function process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgL5K.png)

Comment: For starters, you're ignoring the first element of the array.

Comment: In C index of the first element in an array is zero. So start i=0.

Comment: And your array is of unsigned ints, but you're telling `printf()` they're signed ints, and it looks like your input has negative numbers?

Comment: My assignment says, that the first element of the array(array[0]) is used to represent another value later in the project. So the array in which I have to find min and max is an array from array[1] to array[size-1].

Comment: The problem seems to be that you passed an `int` array to a function handling it as `unsigned int` array. So the value `-1` is converted to big positive value (i.e. the largest unsigned value available).

Comment: So my guess is: `unsigned int *array` --> `int *array`

Comment: In addition to suggestion from 4386427 the members of `min_max_t` must also be adapted.

Comment: @Gerhardh Sure you will get a warning in that case....

Comment: @Gerhardh gcc will not generate warnings for that. Not even with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: @4386427 You are right. That comes as a surprise....

Comment: gcc's `-Wconversion` is not enabled even with `-Wall -Wextra`. It catches the *errors/warnings* in the previous comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For starters the function should be declared like

```
min_max_t min_max( const unsigned int *array, size_t size );
```

and the structure min_max_t should contain two data members that will store indices to minimum and maximum elements. For example

```
typedef struct min_max_t
{
    size_t min;
    size_t max;
} min_max_t;
```

Otherwise the function can invoke undefined behavior when for example the user passed as the second argument 0.

Indices in arrays start from 0. So you skipped within the function the first element of the passed array.

As the array has elements of the type `unsigned int` then the expression `-1` is converted implicitly to the maximum value of the type `unsigned int`. So you need to decide whether indeed you want to deal with unsigned integer arrays or with signed integer arrays.

Using the conversion specifier `%d` instead of `%u` in a call of `printf` to output an object of the type unsigned int can invoke undefined behavior if the value of the object does not fit in an object of the type int.

So your function can look the following way

```
typedef struct min_max_t
{
    size_t min;
    size_t max;
} min_max_t;

min_max_t min_max( const unsigned int *array, size_t size )
{
    min_max_t flag = { .min = 0, .max = 0 };

    printf( "Flag.min: %zu | ", flag.min );
    printf( "Flag.max: %zu\n", flag.max );

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < size; i++ )
    {
        printf( "i = %zu - [A:%u - Min:%u - Max:%u]\n", i, array[i], array[flag.min], array[flag.max] );

        if ( array[flag.max] < arra[i] )
        {
            flag.max = i;
        }
        else if ( array[i] < array[flag.min] )
        {
            flag.min = i;
        }

        printf( "i = %zu - [A:%u - Min:%u - Max:%u]\n\n", i, array[i], array[flag.min], array[flag.max] );
    }

    return flag;
}
```

Comment: @Gerhardh As I already wrote in the answer the user can pass the value 0 for the parameter size. In this case the function will have undefined behavior. You need store indices instead of values of the array.

Comment: Sorry. I overlooked that part.

Comment: Storing indices solves nothing. Btw: `%d` versus `%u` mismatch still present

Comment: Oh, turned out the problem was not in the function block, but in the struct where I had initialized variables as unsigned ints, whereas I needed just regular ints. Thank you very much guys.

Comment: @Leon This solution is complete different from your code....

Comment: @4386427 You are wrong. If to store values then the function in general can have undefined behavior. And there is nothing "complete different".

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Storing indices as 0 for a zero sized array is just as meaningless as returning min/max as zero. And yes, storing indices is completely different from what OP wanted.

Comment: @4386427 Again you are wrong. You should improve your qualification. For example investigate how the standard algorithm std::min_max_element in C++ is declared and defined . It returns iterators instead of values. Otherwise the function will have undefined behavior if it will return values for an empty range.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Indices can not be compared to iterators

Comment: @4386427 As for the conversion specifiers %d I pointed in my answer that it must be substituted for the conversion specifier %u. but due to copy and paste forgot to make updates. It was just a typo.

Comment: @4386427 Again you are entirely wrong. In this context together with with the initial pointer they play the role of iterators.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that `size == 0` and `size == 1` returns the same value.

Comment: @4386427 There is no problem. One again learn C++ algorithms. It will be useful for you.

Comment: nah... that's completely different from what you are doing. If you want to do it C++ alike, you would not pass a size

Comment: @4386427 There is nothing different. For an empty range standard C++ algorithms return the first iterator. The same iterator can be returned for a non-empty range. But using this approach with iterators and indices allows to avoid undefined behavior when instead of iterators or indices such a function tries to return values instead of iterator or indices.  As I mentioned you need to improve your qualification very much. Learn standard C++ algorithms, how they are implemented. It will be very useful for you.

Comment: You are simply wrong

Comment: @4386427 To call an  algorithm for an array with n elements like func( a, a+ n ); is the same as to call it  like  func( a, n ); There is no in fact a difference. As I said you need to lean standard C++algorithms.  I am sorry but I have no desire to continue the discussion with you. You have serious gups in learning C and C++.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the logic for finding min and max.

The problem with your code is that you print **unsigned int** using `%d`. When printing unsigned int values use `%u`.

Another issue, that you may consider to handle, is illegal values of the function parameter `size`. Your function requires that `size` is at least 2. To avoid undefined behavior you may want to check for that.

In the start of the function you could for instance add

```
assert(size >= 2);
```

or

```
if (size < 2)
{
    // return some suitable value
}
```

That said you can also just document the function to require `size` being at least 2. In C it's not uncommon to set such contract requirements for functions. Several stdlib functions have such requirements.

BTW: If you add check for `size` you should probably also check for `array` not being NULL.

BTW: Your Screenshot indicates that you pass an **array of int** to the function. If that's true then you have a bug in the caller-code. Don't pass an **array of int** to a function expecting an **an array of unsigned int**.